# PHPUnit - How do I stub the entire parent class?

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.5

I have a bad situation where a class i want to test is extending another class that has a pretty complex `public static` method. This wouldn't be such an issue if the parent class wasn't extending other classes that are required. In specific, I need `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` to still be extended. My hands are tied regarding possible refactor to make this easier to test.

Is there any way to stub or change the parents of the class in question, while still allowing the Model class to perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could create a `YourClassTestCase` that extends the class you are testing. Then, in `YourClassTestCase` override static method with a simplified return and launch the test over `YourClassTestCase`.

So you will have `YourTest` -> `yourClassTestCase` -> `YourClass` -> `ParentWithStaticMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mock Objects.
See here:https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects

Comment: Standard mocks don't do the trick here. I have to find a way to completely stub the parent class, while keeping the grandparent, or find a way to replace the parent with a different parent. Trying to stub the single static method in the parent would work if I could isolate the scope of `alias` to just the parent.